# Data stays in local datastore after unpinning

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I can't get the unpinning to work and can't find a solution.
I pin the data this way:

```
myGroup = queryGroup.getFirst();
if (myGroup != null) {
    ParseObject.unpinAllInBackground("Groups", new DeleteCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException arg0) {
            myGroup.pinInBackground("Groups", new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException arg0) {
                    if (arg0 != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        arg0.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

and try to unpin it like this:

```
ParseObject.unpinAllInBackground("Groups", new DeleteCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException arg0) {
        if (arg0 == null) {
            dataDeleted();
        } else {
            arg0.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

But it doesn't throw an exception and the data is still saved locally when I start a query.

Comment: How are you sure that the data is local in the query?  Is it possible you've pinned these objects in another tag name?

Comment: I create my Query with: myGroupQuery.fromLocalDatastore(); ... So it should only query locally.

Comment: Ok.  Click the Report a Bug / Bugtool button here:  https://parse.com/help

Comment: please post your code when saving objects

Answer (score 1):

try deleting your local data and try again.  I had some weird issues related to pinning, turned out I had objects pinned with no data in them, which messed up the pinning.

Using the following code, pinallinbackground works, are you able to try that instead of iterating through each object?:

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

      @Override
      public void done(final List<ParseObject> moves, final com.parse.ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
          if (debug) {
            Log.i("bjjMoves returned:", String.valueOf(moves.size()));
          }
          ParseObject.unpinAllInBackground("bjjMoves", new DeleteCallback() {
            public void done(ParseException e) {
              // Cache the new results.
              ParseObject.pinAllInBackground("BJJMove", moves);
            }
          });
```

you'll notice I'm using PinAllInBackground, not pininbackground.